# No recibo respuesta correcta de AWS lambda

Tags: javascript, aws, lambda

Estoy haciendo mis primeros pasos en Lambda AWS, y estoy conectando un proyecto de ionic/Angular con mi lambda en AWS, pero por algún motivo no recibo la respuesta del "Body" que se supone debe de regresar mi lambda.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let nombre = event.name;
    let apellido = event.LastName
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
                headers: {//Tengo este headers por el CORS
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify("Hello " + nombre + " " + apellido),
    };
    return response;
};
```

El output que obtengo:

```
Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
  },
  "body": "\"Hello Bitcoin Etherium\""
}
```

El output que necesito:

```
Hello Bitcoin Etherium
```

Ya le he dado "Deploy" y he usado la herramienta interna para testear valores con el json

```
{
  "name": "Bitcoin",
  "LastName": "Etherium"
}
```

Y me funciona correctamente en la prueba dentro de AWS.
Y en mi codigo tengo lo siguiente:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
 export class RestProvider{

   constructor(public http:HttpClient){
     console.log('Probando desde AWS Lambda')
    }
    ObtenerRespuesta;
    async EscribirAPI(name,LastName){
        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json'
            })
          };
          debugger
          let postData = {name,LastName}
          let Api_URL = "<Mi link de la API>";       
          this.http.post(Api_URL, postData,httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
          this.ObtenerRespuesta = data["body"];//Y es aquí donde no recibo el body, al imprimir
//en consola me sale "Undefine"

        }, error => {
                console.log(error);
    });
  }
 }
```

Es llamado desde la clase principal de la siguente forma:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RestProvider } from '../tab1/tab1lambda';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})

export class Tab1Page implements OnInit{
  
  Nombre = "";
  constructor(public lambdaAWS: RestProvider) { }

  ngOnInit(){}

  async LambdaAPI(nombre, apellido){
   await this.lambdaAWS.EscribirAPI(nombre, apellido);
   this.Nombre =  this.lambdaAWS.ObtenerRespuesta;
   
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Obtienes algún error o simplemente obtienes undefined? Si obtienes algún error sería bueno indicar cuál es el error. En caso de no obtenerlo, ¿podrías indicar cuál es el contenido de `data`?

Comment: @ricardo-dlc solo el undefine

Comment: en vez de acceder a `data["body"]` pon un  `console.log(data)` para ver que contiene `data`

Comment: Como ya te había mencionado y el compañero @hawks reitera, ¿podrías colocar el contenido de `data` que obtienes en tu front? Revisando la [documentación de ejemplo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) dicho mensaje debería estar en el primer nivel del objeto recibido y de ser así parece que el retorno de tu lambda (`body`) debería ser otro objeto.

Comment: @hawks he echo eso y ciertamente me sale "Undefine". Descubrí que al ejecutarlo 2veces funciona, pero eventualmente no es nada correcto hacer 2clicks para que algo funcione

Comment: podrias poner como haces la llamada a la api `EscribirAPI` en tu componente?

Comment: @hawks Actualice la pregunta, se encuentra al final... Gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera de llamar a la API no es correcta. Estas mezclando conceptos de promesas y observables.

Las promesas y observables son abstracciones que nos permiten ejecutar operaciones asíncronas.

Ambos tienen sus casos de uso y sus diferencias.

Por defecto, angular usa los RxJs observables para hacer las llamadas HTTP. Esto se puede cambiar, como lo verás abajo llamando el método `toPromise` sobre un observable.

**Con promesas**

```javascript
EscribirAPI(name,LastName) {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };
    debugger
    let postData = {name,LastName}
    let Api_URL = "<Mi link de la API>";
    return this.http.post(Api_URL, postData,httpOptions).toPromise();
}

// En tu componente
async LambdaAPI(nombre, apellido){
   const respuestaAPI = await this.lambdaAWS.EscribirAPI(nombre, apellido);
   console.log(respuestaAPI);
   this.Nombre =  this.lambdaAWS.ObtenerRespuesta;
}
```

**Con observables**

```
EscribirAPI(name,LastName) {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };
    debugger
    let postData = {name,LastName}
    let Api_URL = "<Mi link de la API>";
    // Esto devolverá un observable
    return this.http.post(Api_URL, postData,httpOptions);
}

// En tu componente
LambdaAPI(nombre, apellido){
   const respuestaAPI = this.lambdaAWS.EscribirAPI(nombre, apellido).subscribe(
      respuestaAPI => {
        console.log(respuestaAPI);  
        this.Nombre = respuestaAPI;
      },
      error => console.error(error)
  );
}
```

Te recomiendo leer sobre Observables y promesas.

Comment: Y hay diferencias de rendimiento?? La verdad solo había leido de promesas, echaré un ojo a observables, muchas gracias!

Comment: es mejor observables(en mi opinión), porque así podrás sacar máximo rendimiento al framework y las funcionalidades que te brinda. Pero para empezar no está mal usar promesas. Problemas de rendimiento no deberías tener.